# Loop through each element and print value in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code where I want to loop through the amount of elements and set the text inside each one from 1 through however many there are. My approach is below:

```js
$(function() {
  var items = $(".item");
  items.each(function(i) {
    var itemCount = i + 1;
    items.text(itemCount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
```

It's however printing the total number 6 times. In this specific example, 6.

The way I understood `.each()` is that it iterates each element individually and my thinking was that I would be able to pass in the value of `itemCount` and have it count each element individually. If I did a regular vanilla JS loop the results in the snippet would make sense since it completes before it prints.

How can I change this approach to print the numbers in order (1 2 3 4 5 6) rather than the total amount of elements 6 times?

Comment: `$(this).text(itemCount)` - items is your array, you want the one specific to the loop

Comment: sidenote, you don't need to iterate yourself. this works too: `$(".item").text(index => index+1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `this` as selector like `$(this)`. `this` referer to the element on each loop.

Currently, you are using `items` which refers to all html elements with class `.item`

```js
$(function() {
  var items = $(".item");
  items.each(function(i) {
    var itemCount = i + 1;
    $(this).text(itemCount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because `items` refers to *all* the elements, so you update every one of them in each iteration. To fix this you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current instance in the `each()` loop.

Better still, you can provide a function to the `text()` method and use the first argument provided to the handler function which is the index of the element. That way you don't need the explicit loop or a reference to the element at all. Try this:

```js
$(".item").text(function(i) {
  return ++i;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

`items` is set to `$(".item");` so you need to specificy which item to use using `$(this)`

```js
$(function() {
  var items = $(".item");
  items.each(function(i) {
    var itemCount = i + 1;
    $(this).text(itemCount);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
<span class="item"></span>
```